# How do I iterate through multiple json dictionaries to check the value of the same type of key?

Tags: python, json, kivy

I want to be able to get the value of "delta" in multiple json dictionaries. I'm using JsonStore from kivy if that changes anything. When I press the button that starts the check_streak function I get  NameError: name 'delta' is not defined.  Here is the code:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json") # file that stores the streaks:


        return presentation

    def check_streak(self, instance):

        for item in self.store.find(delta):

            if delta > time.time():
                print("early")

            if delta == time.time():
                print("on time")

            if delta < time.time():
                print("late")
```

Here is the json dictionary in a seperate file:

```
{"first": {"action": "first", "action_num": "1", "seconds": 60, "score": 0, "delta": 1555714261.0438898}, "second": {"action": "second", "action_num": "2", "seconds": 120, "score": 0, "delta": 1555879741.894656}}
```

I want to be able to get the value of "delta" from every object put inside the file. How would I do this?

Comment: This question doesn't answer the problem I have...

Comment: I’m not trying to generate an id. i just want to compare the value of the delta keys to the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be solved with an item generator to get the value of `'delta'`. Here is the code:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json") # file that stores the streaks:


        return presentation

    # Gets the value of delta (code I may never understand lol)
    def item_generator(self, json_input, lookup_key):
        if isinstance(json_input, dict):
            for k, v in json_input.items():
                if k == lookup_key:
                    yield v
                else:
                    yield from self.item_generator(v, lookup_key)
        elif isinstance(json_input, list):
            for item in json_input:
                yield from self.item_generator(item, lookup_key)

    def check_streak(self, instance):
        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)
            values = self.item_generator(data, 'delta')



        for honey in values:
            if honey > time.time():
                print("early")

            if honey == time.time():
                print("on time")

            if honey < time.time():
                print("late")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the variable `delta` does not exist, hence the error.

Presumably you meant to `for item in self.store.find("delta"):` (with delta as a string)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something like this, where `dd` is `self.store`:

```
In [10]: my_deltas = []

In [11]: for key in dd:
    ...:     my_deltas.append(dd[key].get('delta'))
    ...:

In [12]: my_deltas
Out[12]: [1555714261.0438898, 1555879741.894656]
```